# Is there a more concise way to convert localtime to individual binary lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to take localtime and turn it into individual reversed binary arrays/lists.

Here is my working code:

```
    secs = time.localtime()
    year, month, day, hour, minute, second, weekday, yearday, daylight = secs

    seconds_string = "{0:#b}".format(second)
    seconds_string = seconds_string[2:]
    seconds_list = list(seconds_string[::-1])

    minutes_string = "{0:#b}".format(minute)
    minutes_string = minutes_string[2:]
    minutes_list = list(minutes_string[::-1])

    hours_string = "{0:#b}".format(hour)
    hours_string = hours_string[2:]
    hours_list = list(hours_string[::-1])
```

I would like to make this more concise if possible, but attempts like the following aren't working.

```
    seconds_list = list("{0:#b}".format(second)[2::-1])
```

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is actually

```
seconds_list = list("{0:#b}".format(second)[:1:-1])
```

The syntax is a little weird; slicing is `from:to:step`. This is a `from` of `None`, a `to` of 1, and a step of `-1`; when the step is negative, `from` defaults to the end of the string, so this means "from the end of the string backwards, up to but not including position 1".

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that also works with  `seconds_list = list(bin(second)[:1:-1])`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is:

```
>>> ''.join('{0:#b}'.format(x)[2:] for x in time.localtime())
'11111011100100011110001111001110011110111001'
```

To reverse that you could just add `[::-1]` at the end.

But that does not mean you should do it. Put clarity above shorter code.

Comment: Using a generator expression and not `map` here would make it much more clear IMO: `''.join('{0:#b}'.format(x)[2:] for x in time.localtime())[::-1]`.

Comment: @Dougal: Regarding `map` vs. list comprehension (or generator), this is definitely a matter of personal preference. I usually prefer `map`, if the function is already created (just to avoid `lambda`) and list comprehension when I do something new. You are right, that generator looks nicer here.